# Scheduling IBM Spectrum Protect (TSM) backups via IBM Workload Scheduler (IWS)

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, ibm-tsm

We are switching from CA7 to IWS scheduler.

Currently, the SQL backups scripts are called from CA7 with no issue. That includes a couple of two node SQL Always On Availability Group (AOAG) cluster as well. Since any one of the replicas can be primary (or one of them may not be available) at any given point in time, we use the availability lister name to backup the availability DBs. We are trying to do similar backup from IWS.

Lets say SQL1 and SQL2 are the availability replica instances and SQLAG is the availability listener name.

i'm looking for a way to configure IWS job to be able to run scripts against SQLAG. i'm aware that backup can be done from any replica for AG databases. but, we think it makes sense to use the AG name to initiate the backup as the it can continue to run even when one of the replica is being patched/upgraded etc.,

IWS team tells us that we cannot target a job against an AG name. so, we will have to work around to find which of the replica is primary at any given point in time and call a job which is configured to run against that primary e.g. if SQL1  is primary, call the job which is pointing to SQL1. This looks like a workaround rather than a solution to me.

1. Can IWS use SQL AG name to direct script execution? if so, how to do it? Currently, the dropdown in IWS doesn't list the AG listener name.
2. Is there a plugin for TSM in IWS which can work better together?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try asking your vendor, IBM, these questions?

Comment: Yes, we started that route and asked IWS consultant. The feedback we got was there is apparently no way for IWS to direct a script execution using AG node name. So thought to ask in this forum to see if anyone has gone through similar situation.